# Databricks SQL reading Parquet file ceated by Copy activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, parquet, databricks-sql

I'm tyring to get a Parquet file written by a Azore Data Factory copy activity "attached" to Databricks SQL.
I used this command

```
create table people_db.GLAccount USING PARQUET LOCATION "abfss://dlsxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/datamesh/PricingAnalysis/rdv_60_134.vGLAccount.parquet"
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Abfss://dlsxxxx.core.windows.net/datamesh/PricingAnalysis/rdv_60_134.vGLAccount.parquet has invalid authority.
```

I'm not a databricsk expert and I saw that the ADF-Copy writes all data into 1 file and when I create Parquet files in Databricks I'm getting a directory with several files into it. So this might all have something to do with setting, but I will need some guidance on where what to change/test...

Kr, Harry

Comment: Ok, found out that the container has to be up front the storage name, so "datamesh@dlsxxx." did part of the trick, but then I run into credential problems. With a databricks Clsuter we have passthrough AAd enabled, how can I handle this here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the `datamesh` is your container on ADLS? If yes, then URL should be

```
abfss://datamesh@dlsxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/PricingAnalysis/rdv_60_134.vGLAccount.parquet
```

In general, ABFSS urls look like following:

```
abfss://<container>@<storage>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>
```

P.S. you can find all details in [documentation for Hadoop ABFSS integration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/abfs.html).

Comment: Correct, now I'm struggling with credentials (when done with Databricks SQL), in Python pysql it work.

Comment: You need to specify them in admin console. Some properties like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage#azureserviceprincipal